# Selecting a point by ID using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using Highcharts, how can I select a point using it's id? For example, if I create a chart using the following code:

```
 chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'scatter'
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
         },
         xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
         },
         yAxis: {
            title: {
               text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
         },
         series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [{
                name: 'Point1',
                x: 1,
                y: 2
            }, {
                name: 'Point2',
                x: 2,
                y: 5
            }]
         }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
         }]
      });
   });
```

The tooltip tells me that when I hover over a point, what the id is. However, I can't figure out the syntax to identify that point. I know that `chart1.series[0].name` returns `Jane. Also,`
chart1.series[0].data[0].name`returns`point1` Is there an easy way that I can just select the point and change the color knowing only 'point1'?

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way other than looping through all of the points each time.

Comment: Reading the API documentation is always the best way to learn how to accomplish tasks.. and it's an alternative and efficient source of learning / training. :)

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: I asked this question almost two years ago. At that point it was not discussed in the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set an `id` for each point you want to get.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [{
        'name': 'Point1',
        'id': 'point1',
        'x': 1,
        'y': 2
    }, {
        'name': 'Point2',
        'id': 'point2',
        'x': 2,
        'y': 5
    }]
}, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 7, 3]
}]
```

Then you can get the point by the following code.

```
// assuming that chart is your chart var
chart.get('point1');
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WRcj9/47/)

Or if you don't want to set an `id` you can simple loop thrue `points` to compare the `name` you want to find with the `point name`.

*Reference*:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#object-Chart

Comment: clean, simple and efficient.

Comment: Except it's not efficient. Clean and simple remains true but behind the scenes HighChart's "chart.get()" method is iterating through every series and every single point in that series to find a match. It's O(n) on data sets that are already sorted by x value anyways. So a binary search implemented by the application developer using highcharts would offer better efficiency since you can at least get O(log N) searching it yourself.