# Highlight point in Highcharts scatter graph?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts scatter graph and I would like to let the user search for a particular point by id or name, and highlight it.

I've been reading the Highcharts docs, but I can't see how to do this programmatically.

For now I've just coded up a simple demo with a button: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/scatter/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    ...
});
$('#clickme').click(function() { 
    console.log('clicked'); 
    // how to highlight a particular point, say by 
    // value or by name?
});
```

I would like to extend it so that if the user clicks the button, a point in the chart (in this case it can just be selected by index) gets highlighted.

Is this possible in Highcharts?

I guess I could fire a 'click' or 'hover' event on the point if there is no other way to highlight it, maybe?

Comment: Made a first attempt http://jsfiddle.net/3d1ptuL1/ though it's kind of fugly... would be keen to know if there's a nicer way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call setState function on point and then apply SELECT / HOVER.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
        chart.series[0].data[2].setState('hover'); //alternatively SELECT state.
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/74s1cbmq/1/

Comment: Can we select setState based on point name? for example, if my dataset have { name: 'Argentina', x: 39, y: 946935.6 } can we select point named 'Argentina'?

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to get the point in question:
[Selecting a point by ID using Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717643/selecting-a-point-by-id-using-highcharts)

Then you can select it (in code):
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.selected

which will cause this event to fire:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.select

Comment: Actually the "get point by ID" only seems to be an option in Highstock, not Highcharts...